# I want to calculate all of the values of the previous month and compare them to the current month

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, laravel-5, vuejs2

I'm using laravel for my backend and vue components to build my frontend. My goal is to grab all the data from the totals table with the type of: 'tips' and compare my current month of entries to my previous month of entries and calculate a percentage to show either a gain/loss. I've got everything except actually segregating the data by current & previous month.

This is the code for my totals widget so far. The part I'm stuck on is Comparing the months where I have it just console logging the res data.(The current data was dummy data to test my percentages)

```js
   name: "TotalsWidget",
    props: ['type'],
    data() {
        return {
            desc: 'Tips',
            percentage: 0,
            thisMonth: 100,
            lastMonth: 500,
            total: 5477,
            state: null,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getData(type){
            axios.get('/api/totals/'+ type).then((res) => {      
                /* Adding totals together */
                let total = [];
                Object.entries(res.data).forEach(([key, val]) => {
                    total.push(val.value)
                });
                this.total = total.reduce((total, num) => {return total + num}, 0);

                /* Compare Months */ 
                let months = [];
                console.log(res.data)
            });           
        }
    },
    computed:{
        getPercentage(thisMonth, lastMonth){
            this.percentage = Math.floor((this.thisMonth - this.lastMonth) / this.lastMonth * 100);
            if(Math.sign(this.percentage) == 1){
              return this.state = 'mdi mdi-arrow-up-drop-circle text-success mr-1'
            } else {
              return this.state = 'mdi mdi-arrow-down-drop-circle mr-1 text-danger'
            }
        },
    },
    mounted(){
        this.getData(this.type);
        console.log('Tips Widget Loaded');     
    }
```

Here is what's in my res.data:

```
[{…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, type: "tips", desc: "Tips", value: 740, created_at: "2019-05-22 03:46:25", …}
1: {id: 2, type: "tips", desc: "Tips", value: 1105, created_at: "2019-04-22 03:46:25", …}
```

Theres going to be entries every monday this is just some dummy data to try to get it working. I'm unsure how to go about comparing the two and if I should use javascripts Date function or a third party like moment.js and how to go about doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've got it working in a very messy way but it works.

```js
        getData(type){
            axios.get('/api/totals/'+ type).then((res) => {    

                let data = res.data;

                /* Adding totals together */
                let total = [];

                Object.entries(res.data).forEach(([key, val]) => {
                    total.push(val.value)
                    return val.created_at = moment(val.created_at).format("YY-MM")
                });
                this.total = total.reduce((total, num) => {return total + num}, 0);

                /* Compare Months */ 
                let currentMonth = moment(moment().format()).format("YY-MM")
                let previousMonth = moment(this.currentMonth).subtract(1, 'months').format("YY-MM")
                let calculateThisMonth = [];
                let calculateLastMonth = [];

                /* Calculating this Months */
                let thisMonth = data.filter((total) => {       
                    return total.created_at == currentMonth
                })
                Object.entries(thisMonth).forEach(([key, val]) => {
                    calculateThisMonth.push(val.value)
                });                        
                this.thisMonth = calculateThisMonth.reduce((total, num) => {return total + num}, 0);   

                /* Calculating last Months */
                let lastMonth = data.filter((total) => {       
                    return total.created_at == previousMonth
                })
                Object.entries(lastMonth).forEach(([key, val]) => {
                    calculateLastMonth.push(val.value)
                });                        
                this.lastMonth = calculateLastMonth.reduce((total, num) => {return total + num}, 0);   
            });           
        }
```

I feel like there is defintely a better way and if you've got any criticism i'd love to hear it